# Execute an .sql file in unix using org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils

Tags: java, spring, unix

I have sql file present in my unix server. I want to run that file in unix using java program.
I saw many ways online, I tried using `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils`

The code is follows

```
try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String URL = configBean.getUrl();
        String USER = configBean.getUser();
        String PASS = configBean.getPassword();
        System.out.println(URL + " ,"+USER+" ,"+PASS);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER,PASS);
        System.out.println(configBean.getSqlFilePath());
        ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(conn, new ClassPathResource(configBean.getSqlFilePath()));
```

The problem is this method is unable to detect the file in the unix server. I have path present in a config file. From there I'm reading the path, My path is "/home/applvis/JAVA/UAT/config/ABC.sql".
When I execute the jar containing this code, it shows the file not found in this location. It removes the first slash present in the file path. If I put two slashes then also it is unable to detect the file. The error which I get is

```
INFO: Executing SQL script from class path resource [/home/applvis/JAVA/UAT/config/ALLOT010T_OBJNAMES.sql]
Exception in thread "Main Thread" org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [/home/applvis/JAVA/UAT/config/ALLOT010T_OBJNAMES.sql]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [/home/applvis/JAVA/UAT/config/ALLOT010T_OBJNAMES.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:442)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:395)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:373)
        at com.acc.directory.scanner.SDScanner.main(SDScanner.java:77)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [/home/applvis/JAVA/UAT/config/ALLOT010T_OBJNAMES.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:143)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getReader(EncodedResource.java:92)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.readScript(ScriptUtils.java:279)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:439)
        ... 3 more
```

I'm unable to understand what am I doing wrong or is there a different way to read files from unix. Please help

Comment: Have you checked the access rights permission for that directory and file. Try giving 777 access.

Comment: I gave 777 access to the files and tried. It is still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You wrote your file lies in your filesystem under `/home/applvis/JAVA/UAT/config/ABC.sql`, but your code is trying to load to file from the classpath.

So instead of

```
ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(conn, new ClassPathResource(configBean.getSqlFilePath()));
```

you have to use

```
ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(conn, new FileSystemResource(configBean.getSqlFilePath()));
```